# VBA - How do I convert Date into String

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date column in EXCEL with the date in the format - 1/27/2019. I want to write a script in VBA to extract just the year portion (2019) and put it in another column.

Do I convert the Date into String first? And then split the String using

```
`Split(date_as_string, "/")
```

to get the year portion??

How can I convert the Date into String to achieve this? Any other approach to solve this problem is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your date column is in true date format then Excel `YEAR` Function can be used to return value of the year in another column. Date reflected in column in this case is in my system local date format. It may be different in your system but `YEAR` will work as per your date system.

[image: year_snapshot]

EDIT:
If you want to go for VBA then example of macro is:

```
Sub Year_Only()
    Dim yr As String
    yr = Year(Range("A1"))
    Range("B1").Value = yr
End Sub
```

[image: year_vba]

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
Sub JustYear()
    Dim yr As Long
    yr = Split(Range("A1").Text, "/")(2)
    Range("B1").Value = yr
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For text representing the year,

```
range("A1") = format(cdate(date_as_string), "yyyy")
```

To get a true number representing the year,

```
range("A1") = val(format(cdate(date_as_string), "yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Year() function:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim yea As Integer
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("a1")
    yea = year(r.Value)
    Debug.Print yea
End Sub
```